# RijndaelManaged Decryption Issue

Tags: c#, encryption, rijndaelmanaged

I support a huge C++ system developed originally in the early 1990's.  (I have mentioned this system in other posts of mine)  We are in the process of developing all new C# applications to replace the older C++ systems.  Using TcpClient, unencrypted or encrypted commands are sent to and from our C# applications to the C++ system. (encryption is a selectable feature).  Unencrypted commands are both sent and received without issue.  The encrypted commands are a different story.  We can successfully encrypt our commands and the C++ system will accept those commands.  However, encrypted messages sent FROM C++ TO our C# system, don't decrypt correctly.  I have gotten a few decryptions to not fail, but they all result in a cryptic string.  The encryption uses RijndaelManaged and a CryptoStream, that originated from the early 1990s.  If anybody out there can get the decryption code to work, I'd say good things about you for many years to come :-) (if you are wondering why we don't replace the encryption style for something simpler, it is because several other older C++ systems still use this technique)

For sending the encrypted command, this works correctly:

```
        //Generic messages array
        var messages = new string[4];
        messages[0] = "";
        messages[1] = "Service Manager";
        messages[2] =
            "<COMMAND_BLOCK><OPERATOR User=\"1234\" Password=\"password\"/>" +
            "<COMMAND Target=\"targetServer\" Command=\"1024\" " +
            "Data=\"1\" Priority=\"HIGH\" Id=\"-1\" " +
            "Workstation=\"Server1\"/></COMMAND_BLOCK>{Convert.ToChar(10)}";
        messages[3] = IsEncryptionEnabled ? "1" : "0"; 


                var formattedMessage = $"{messages[1]}{Convert.ToChar(10)}{messages[2]}";
                formattedMessage =
                    $"{Convert.ToChar(messages[2].Length)}{Convert.ToChar((int)Math.Floor((double)messages[2].Length / 255))}{formattedMessage}";

                if (WebApiCommon.Globals.IsEncryptionEnabled) //Yes, encryption is crazy
                {
                    var commandBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messages[2]);
                    var messageLength = commandBytes.Length;
                    var allocatedLength = messageLength;
                    var blockLength = 16;

                    allocatedLength = ((messageLength + blockLength - 1) / blockLength) * blockLength;

                    var messageBytes = new byte[allocatedLength];

                    for (var x = 0; x < allocatedLength; x++)
                    {
                        if (x < messageLength)
                            messageBytes[x] = commandBytes[x];
                        else // pad out for encryption
                            messageBytes[x] = 0;
                    }

                    while (keyString.Length < 16) // make sure keystring is exactly 16 bytes.
                        keyString += keyString;
                    if (keyString.Length > 16)
                        keyString = keyString.Substring(0, 16);
                    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252); // ANSI 1252

                    var key = encoding.GetBytes(keyString);

                    //create empty IV
                    var iv = new byte[16];
                    for (var x = 0; x < iv.Length; x++)
                        iv[x] = 0;

                    //create encryption object
                    var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged
                    {
                        BlockSize = 128,
                        KeySize = 128,
                        Padding = PaddingMode.None
                    };

                    //break into blockLength byte blocks and encrypt

                    var block = new byte[blockLength];
                    var encryptedBytes = new byte[allocatedLength];
                    for (var x = 0; x < allocatedLength; x += blockLength)
                    {
                        // copy current block
                        for (var j = 0; j < blockLength; j++)
                            block[j] = messageBytes[x + j];

                        using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            using (var cs1 = new CryptoStream(ms1, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                                cs1.Write(block, 0, block.Length);
                            var block1 = ms1.ToArray();
                            for (var j = 0; j < blockLength; j++)
                                encryptedBytes[x + j] = block1[j];
                        }
                    }
                    var lsbMessageLength = new byte[2];

                    lsbMessageLength[0] = (byte)(allocatedLength & 0xFF);
                    lsbMessageLength[1] = (byte)(((allocatedLength >> 8) & 0xF) + 0x40); // 0x40 = flag to enable encryption

                    var controlPortStream = controlConnection.GetStream();
                    controlPortStream.Write(lsbMessageLength, 0, lsbMessageLength.Length);
                    controlPortStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
                    controlPortStream.Flush();
                }
```

I am including all my decryption code attempts, commented out, along with the decryption code I would expect to work, but doesn't.  If anybody can see what I'm doing wrong, please let me know (code preferred):

```
    private string DecryptMPString(string incomingMessage)
    {
        var keyString =
            WebApiCommon.ApiRequests.SysSettings.GetList(new SysSettingDto { SectionName = "Configuration", VariableName = "Site name" }).FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

        var encryptedBytes2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(incomingMessage);
        var encryptedBytes = ConvertHexToAscii(encryptedBytes2);

        var messageLength = encryptedBytes.Length;
        var allocatedLength = messageLength;
        var blockLength = 16;

        allocatedLength = ((messageLength + blockLength - 1) / blockLength) * blockLength;

        var messageBytes = new byte[allocatedLength];

        for (var x = 0; x < allocatedLength; x++)
        {
            if (x < messageLength)
                messageBytes[x] = encryptedBytes[x];
            else // pad out for encryption
                messageBytes[x] = 0;
        }

        while (keyString.Length < 16) // make sure keystring is exactly 16 bytes.
            keyString += keyString;
        if (keyString.Length > 16)
            keyString = keyString.Substring(0, 16);
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252); // ANSI 1252

        var key = encoding.GetBytes(keyString);

        //create empty IV
        var iv = new byte[16];
        for (var x = 0; x < iv.Length; x++)
            iv[x] = 0;

        //create encryption object
        //var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged
        //{
        //    BlockSize = 128,
        //    KeySize = 128,
        //    Padding = PaddingMode.None
        //};

        //break into blockLength byte blocks and encrypt

        //var block = new byte[blockLength];
        //var decryptedBytes = new byte[allocatedLength];
        //for (var x = 0; x < allocatedLength; x += blockLength)
        //{
        //    // copy current block
        //    for (var j = 0; j < blockLength; j++)
        //        block[j] = messageBytes[x + j];

        using (var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijndael.BlockSize = 128;
            rijndael.KeySize = 128;
            rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            var decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);

            var decryptedBytes = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(messageBytes, 0, allocatedLength);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
        }

        //using (var encryptedStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes))
        //    {
        //        using (var decryptedStream = new MemoryStream())
        //        {
        //            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, rijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        //            {
        //                int data;
        //                while ((data = cryptoStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
        //                    decryptedStream.WriteByte((byte)data);
        //            }

        //            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedStream.ToArray(), 0, decryptedStream.ToArray().Length);
        //            //var block1 = decryptedStream.ToArray();
        //        //for (var j = 0; j < blockLength; j++)
        //        //    decryptedBytes[x + j] = block1[j];
        //    }
        //}
        //}
        
        // return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);


        //using (var encryptedStream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(incomingMessage)))
        //{
        //    //stream where decrypted contents will be stored
        //    using (var decryptedStream = new MemoryStream())
        //    {
        //        using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged { KeySize = 128, BlockSize = 128, Padding = PaddingMode.None })
        //        {
        //            using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
        //            {
        //                //decrypt stream and write it to parent stream
        //                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        //                {
        //                    int data;

        //                    while ((data = cryptoStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
        //                        decryptedStream.WriteByte((byte)data);
        //                }
        //            }
        //        }

        //        //reset position in prep for reading
        //        decryptedStream.Position = 0;
        //        var decryptedBytes = decryptedStream.ToArray();
        //        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
        //    }
        //}

    }

    private static byte[] ConvertHexToAscii(byte[] hexBytes)
    {
        int newLength = (hexBytes.Length) / 2;
        var buffer = new byte[newLength];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < newLength; i++, j += 2)
            buffer[i] = (byte)(((hexBytes[j] - '0') << 4) + (hexBytes[j + 1] - '0'));

        return buffer;
    }
```

This is days after the initial question, but here is the C++ Encrypt code used for creating the message that is picked up by my C# solution:

```
  BYTE* CEncrypt::Encrypt(LPCTSTR pszData,WORD& nLength)
  {
    if(nLength && m_bEncryptEnabled && m_nBlockSize == 16)
    {
        int nBufferSize = m_nBlockSize * (nLength/m_nBlockSize + (nLength %       m_nBlockSize == 0?0:1));
        BYTE* cBuffer = new BYTE[nBufferSize];
        if(cBuffer)
        {
            memcpy(cBuffer,pszData,nLength);
            while (nLength < nBufferSize)   // zero last bytes in case short
                    cBuffer[nLength++] = '\0';
            for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < nLength; nIndex += m_nBlockSize)
            {
                Encrypt(cBuffer + nIndex);      
            }
        return cBuffer;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
  }

  /* There is an obvious time/space trade-off possible here.     *
   * Instead of just one ftable[], I could have 4, the other     *
   * 3 pre-rotated to save the ROTL8, ROTL16 and ROTL24 overhead */ 
  void CEncrypt::Encrypt(BYTE *buff)
  {
      int i,j,k,m;
      DWORD a[8],b[8],*x,*y,*t;

      for (i=j=0; i<Nb; i++,j+=4)
      {
          a[i] = pack((BYTE *)&buff[j]);
          a[i] ^= fkey[i];
      }
      k = Nb;
      x = a;
      y = b;

    /* State alternates between a and b */
      for (i=1; i<Nr; i++)
      { /* Nr is number of rounds. May be odd. */

        /* if Nb is fixed - unroll this next loop and hard-code in the values       of fi[]  */

          for (m=j=0; j<Nb; j++,m+=3)
          { /* deal with each 32-bit element of the State */
            /* This is the time-critical bit */
              y[j]=fkey[k++]^ftable[(BYTE)x[j]]^
                   ROTL8(ftable[(BYTE)(x[fi[m]]>>8)])^
                   ROTL16(ftable[(BYTE)(x[fi[m+1]]>>16)])^
                   ROTL24(ftable[x[fi[m+2]]>>24]);
          }
          t = x;
          x = y;
          y = t;      /* swap pointers */
      }

    /* Last Round - unroll if possible */ 
      for (m=j=0; j<Nb; j++,m+=3)
      {
          y[j] = fkey[k++]^(DWORD)fbsub[(BYTE)x[j]]^
               ROTL8((DWORD)fbsub[(BYTE)(x[fi[m]]>>8)])^
               ROTL16((DWORD)fbsub[(BYTE)(x[fi[m+1]]>>16)])^
               ROTL24((DWORD)fbsub[x[fi[m+2]]>>24]);
      }   

      for (i=j=0; i<Nb; i++,j+=4)
      {
          unpack(y[i], (BYTE *)&buff[j]);
          x[i] = y[i] = 0;   /* clean up stack */
      }
      return;
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is the format of `incomingMessage`? You seem to be using its UTF8 bytestream as the ciphertext, which is probably not right.

Comment: I added the command text to the top of the code

Comment: @JonathanHansen There's still something missing - how do the encrypted bytes sent over the wire get turned into a `string` (`incomingMessage`)? Where is `DecryptMPString()` being called from?

Comment: Thanks for adding the command text, but I asked about the format of `incomingMessage`, which I assume is encrypted, and therefore not the same as the cleartext command text. Is it a base64 encoded string? Is it a string of hexadecimal digits?

Comment: Oh.  The data is received from the TcpClient like so:

while (_continueListening && (i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
 {
// Translate data bytes to an ASCII string and add it to the data string. (this data is passed into the DecryptMPString method)
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

Comment: Upon answering these questions, I am questioning how I take the byte array from the listener, convert it to ASCII string, then convert it again in the decrypt code to a UTF8 byte array.

Comment: I think what is supposed to happen is `string input > hex decode into byte array > decrypt > UTF8-decode bytes into a string`

Comment: Hey, I just added the C++ code to my original question, at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your encrypt code creates a new encryptor for each block:

```
for (var x = 0; x < allocatedLength; x += blockLength)
{
    // copy current block
    for (var j = 0; j < blockLength; j++)
        block[j] = messageBytes[x + j];

    using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cs1 = new CryptoStream(ms1, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            cs1.Write(block, 0, block.Length);
        var block1 = ms1.ToArray();
        for (var j = 0; j < blockLength; j++)
            encryptedBytes[x + j] = block1[j];
    }
}
```

... which makes it essentially an ECB transform.  The C++ code is doing the same thing.

On your C# Decrypt, you attempt to decrypted the whole block at once:

```
using (var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
{
    rijndael.BlockSize = 128;
    rijndael.KeySize = 128;
    rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
    var decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
    var decryptedBytes = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(messageBytes, 0, allocatedLength);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
}
```

...which will work for the first block, but not the rest.  Change it to process each block with a new decryptor...and it will work:

```
string finalString = "";
var blockLength = 16;
using (var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
{
    rijndael.BlockSize = 128;
    rijndael.KeySize = 128;
    rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
    for (var bytePos = 0; bytePos < allocatedLength; bytePos += blockLength)
    {
        var decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
        var decryptedBytes = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(messageBytes.Skip(bytePos).ToArray(), 0, blockLength);
        finalString += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
    }
}
return finalString;
```

Comment: Brilliant!  This solved it!  Decryption finally works between the c++ system and my c# system!  Excellent find!!

Answer (score 2):

With a problem like this, it's generally best to break it down into the smallest component you can.  In this case, you should sperate the encryption and decryption function from all other logic.  That will let you test those functions, compare their output to known good functions, and just be able to run through the code without too much work:

```cs
static byte[] Encrypt(string[] messages)
{
    string keyString = "mysupersecretkey";

    var formattedMessage = $"{messages[1]}{Convert.ToChar(10)}{messages[2]}";
    formattedMessage =
        $"{Convert.ToChar(messages[2].Length)}{Convert.ToChar((int)Math.Floor((double)messages[2].Length / 255))}{formattedMessage}";

    if (true /*WebApiCommon.Globals.IsEncryptionEnabled*/) //Yes, encryption is crazy
    {
        var commandBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formattedMessage);
        // Create a buffer block-aligned that's big enough for commandBytes
        var messageBytes = new byte[((commandBytes.Length - 1) | 15) + 1];
        // Copy commandBytes into the buffer
        Buffer.BlockCopy(commandBytes, 0, messageBytes, 0, commandBytes.Length);

        while (keyString.Length < 16) // make sure keystring is exactly 16 bytes.
            keyString += keyString;
        if (keyString.Length > 16)
            keyString = keyString.Substring(0, 16);
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252); // ANSI 1252

        var key = encoding.GetBytes(keyString);

        //create empty IV
        var iv = new byte[16];

        //create encryption object
        var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged
        {
            BlockSize = 128,
            KeySize = 128,
            Padding = PaddingMode.None
        };

        using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Encrypt messageBytes
            using (var cs1 = new CryptoStream(ms1, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                cs1.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
            var encryptedBytes = ms1.ToArray();

            // Create the message length
            var lsbMessageLength = new byte[2];
            lsbMessageLength[0] = (byte)(encryptedBytes.Length & 0xFF);
            lsbMessageLength[1] = (byte)(((encryptedBytes.Length >> 8) & 0xF) + 0x40); // 0x40 = flag to enable encryption

            // Combine the message length along with the encrypted bytes
            byte[] ret = new byte[lsbMessageLength.Length + encryptedBytes.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(lsbMessageLength, 0, ret, 0, lsbMessageLength.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytes, 0, ret, lsbMessageLength.Length, encryptedBytes.Length);
            // Return it
            return ret;
        }
    }
}

static string Decrypt(byte[] encryptedBytes)
{
    string keyString = "mysupersecretkey";

    // Get the message bytes from the bytes
    var allocatedLength = (encryptedBytes[1] & 0xF) << 8 | encryptedBytes[0];
    // And pull out the encrypted bytes
    var messageBytes = new byte[allocatedLength];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytes, 2, messageBytes, 0, allocatedLength);

    while (keyString.Length < 16) // make sure keystring is exactly 16 bytes.
        keyString += keyString;
    if (keyString.Length > 16)
        keyString = keyString.Substring(0, 16);
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252); // ANSI 1252

    var key = encoding.GetBytes(keyString);

    //create empty IV
    var iv = new byte[16];
    for (var x = 0; x < iv.Length; x++)
        iv[x] = 0;

    using (var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijndael.BlockSize = 128;
        rijndael.KeySize = 128;
        rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        var decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
        var decryptedBytes = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(messageBytes, 0, allocatedLength);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

You can then exercise this with a few quick calls:

```cs
string[] messages = { "", "system name", "Command" };
var encrypted = Encrypt(messages);
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(encrypted).Replace("-", ""));
var decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted);
Console.WriteLine(decrypted);
```

Which outputs:

```
2040622E097E5E8D438C9156384757A56C83B764BDF5B0D34346B2A7D56BD96016D7
 system name
Command
```

You can then verify the encrypted string is correct against the C++ implementation, and that the decrypted response without running through the rest of the network code.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and created a new project to test the encrypt/decrypt, and my code worked fine.  However, since the encrypted code coming from the c++ application still doesn't work, I have to presume the encrypted bytes I'm receiving are slightly different.  So I just added the C++ code to my original question, at the bottom.  Maybe this will shed some light onto the difference.